FlutterLoader.loadEntrypoint" is deprecated. Use "FlutterLoader.load" instead
When updating Flutter to the new version 3.22.0, I encountered a warning:
"The use of 'FlutterLoader.loadEntrypoint' is deprecated. Please use 'FlutterLoader.load' instead."
After making the change from 'loadEntrypoint' to 'load', I encountered another issue:
"FlutterLoader.load requires _flutter.buildConfig to be set"

Upon reviewing flutter.js, I realized that the 'load' function has more parameters than 'loadEntrypoint'

I would like to ask if anyone knows the solution to this problem, please provide suggestions.

I've encountered this issue just today, spent a bit of time looking at the documentation and release notes and this is what i found:
https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/bootstrapping
They have improved web app initialization:

They made a simpler callback for projects created from 3.22.0 and above. Just replace the content your index.html, your code should look like this:

    <body>
      <script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>
    </body>


For more complex cases you can still use the old syntax with a couple of extra steps. For example here i'm setting a splash Logo image which gets removed when flutter loaded:

<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      {{flutter_js}}
      {{flutter_build_config}}
      
      _flutter.loader.load({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: {{flutter_service_worker_version}},
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            if(document.getElementById('splash'))
              document.getElementById('splash').remove();
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  <picture id="splash"   >
    <source srcset="splash/img/iso_gradient_vert-x3.png 1x" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light) or (prefers-color-scheme: no-preference)">
    <source srcset="splash/img/iso_gradient_vert-x3.png 1x" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
    <img class="center" src="splash/img/iso_gradient_vert-x3.png" width="500" height="500"  alt="LOGO"/>
  </picture>
</body>

Hope it helps!

So this works, runs and removes the error in console, however, I'm getting compile timne errors in the index file around the {{flutter_service_worker_version}} line?
Anyone seeing the same and/or solution?

HTML is not compiled. The error is likely just your IDE complaining, because it doesn't recognize the template syntax that flutter is using. You can ignore those errors.

I think the best way to handle this issue is to upgrade an older flutter project as mentioned in the Flutter documentation.
What I did was remove the files from /web directory, then run the following command: flutter create . --platforms=web
Reference:
https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/bootstrapping

If you have done any customization within the /web directory, such as adding statically hosted pages or additions to the index.html page, you'd need to be very careful to make sure you're saving those additions.
